# How to use cloud flare wrangler to upload assets to pages production environment

Tags: cloudflare, wrangler

The following command didn't upload my assets as production on the pages site.
It was always uploaded as preview.

There is no wrangler.toml in my project

```
npx wrangler pages deploy --project-name=$project_name ./dist/apps/player2
```

The following didn't work:

- using --env=production
- using --branch=production

Answer (score 0):

What worked is creating the project with production branch set as the same branch I was going to upload later.

```
npx wrangler pages project create $project_name --production-branch=$release_branch

npx wrangler pages deploy --project-name=$project_name ./dist/apps/player2 --branch=$release_branch
```